# How to find column values which contains unique value in another column from same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
  Id  name  value
0 1   aaa   x
1 2   aaa   y
2 3   aaa   z
3 4   ddd   t
4 5   ddd   t
5 6   fff   j
6 7   ggg   m
7 8   ggg   n
```

I want to find only those rows whose names are duplicate and for these duplicate rows the values are different.

**Expected output :**

```
  Id name  value
 0 1   aaa   x
 1 2   aaa   y
 2 3   aaa   z
 3 7   ggg   m
 4 8   ggg   n
```

I'm trying with [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.groupby('name')
```

Is this groupby function usefull for this task? How I can achieve what I want exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code will count the number of values by name:

```
df.groupby('name')['value'].transform(pd.Series.nunique)
Out[8]: 
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    2
7    2
```

Note that I use `.transform(pd.Series.nunique)` rather than simply `.nunique()` on the `groupby` object. This way, the result will be of the same length as the original dataframe, and you can use it directly for filtering:

```
df[df.groupby('name')['value'].transform(pd.Series.nunique) > 1]
Out[9]: 
   Id name value
0   1  aaa     x
1   2  aaa     y
2   3  aaa     z
6   7  ggg     m
7   8  ggg     n
```